# what type of Monitoring we need to use to determine the size of the message put on a queue

Tags: ibm-mq

An application puts a batch of messages onto a local queue for processing.
What type of monitoring does the system administrator need to enable and which value indicates the size of the messages that we put on the queue.
Can I enable queue accounting on the queue and review the PutBytes value or enable queue statistics on the queue manager and review the MaxMsgLength.
I am not very clear which queue I need to enable for my abovemonitoring purpose.  SYSTEM.ADMIN.ACCOUNTING.QUEUE or SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear about the 'use case'.

(1) Do you want to do a quick check after the batch of messages?  If so, then simply start MQ Explorer, select the queue, right click and select Browse Messages. There will be 2 columns of interest: Data Length and Total Length (the values will be the same except for MQRFH2 messages).

(2) Do you want a non-human, on-going monitoring/tracking of the messages? If so, there is nothing in the product that will do that.  You can find a list of commercial products [here](http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html).  If you want a light-weight commercial solution then have a look at [MQ Auditor](http://www.capitalware.com/mqa_overview.html).  Note: I'm the developer of MQ Auditor.

Comment: Thanks Roger for your immediate response.Can I enable queue accounting on the queue and review the PutBytes value or enable queue statistics on the queue manager and review the MaxMsgLength.
I am not very clear which queue I need to enable for my abovemonitoring purpose.  SYSTEM.ADMIN.ACCOUNTING.QUEUE or SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE